# How to redirect to a page and re-render that page at the same time

Tags: reactjs

So I have buttons with functions in them in my React JS app and if the user hits the button(for example: Save) I have them redirect to the home page using `history.push("/home");`. This works good however it doesn't re-render my home page so none of the data that was updated is shown. I'm wondering how I can redirect to and re-render that home page when a user clicks on Save.

Comment: React does re-render when after data changes (props changes). Whatever you used - MobX, Appollo, React Contexts, or even Redux - when data in store changes it must update your views. So, question is what did you do wrong with data update

Comment: @user2541867 Should I have something in componentDidUpdate or something? How does my react component know that it has updated?

Comment: it's not about componentDidUpdate. Let's assume you have someList array, this array is passed to home component: <Home array={someArray}>. When you change your array then component will be updated automatically in case of using mobx, will be updated after dispatching change in case of Redux, I don't know how in case of Apollo and please don't do it using just plain React states.

Comment: In old-school js you need to update views i.e make re-render of html manually, in new school frameworks just forget about it, let framework update view while you are working with data

Comment: @user2541867 I'm not using Redux or anything. Just regular states. The component is getting updated with data from my database and I'm using a fetch request to get that data in componentDidMount

Comment: If you are redirecting form other page to home page, then home should render, componentDidMount should load data, why is it not working? You asked about re-render, but in case of redirecting it should render anyway

Comment: Im using React Router so I don't think it re-renders

Comment: Aha, found a solution:
<Route path="/home">
  <Home />
</Route>
You are using it this way, so all components gets rendered no matter what current location is.

<Route path="/home" component={Home} />
Just use it this way and it will re-render

Comment: I used both these and they didn't work :/

Comment: Giving up, it had to work, with <Route component={}/> it should render each time switching page, try to debug why it doesn't, and consider using mobx or apollo for data managing, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using React Router LINK

```
import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then use it like this:

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

This will change the history.

You can also add `onClick` functions to it as well.

Comment: Idk why but nothing happens when I use this on my button